# Need Processing help, draw random sets of buildings?

Tags: processing

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 500);
}

float x=20;
int y=480;
int aptSize=20;
float a, e;
float currentFloor=0;
float s;
float offset;
//float aptNum;
void draw() {

  //draw sky
  //  sky();
  float n=0;    

// if(keyPressed){
 // sky();

  //draw a building
  for (int f=0; f<3 && x<600; f++, x = x + ((n*20)+20)) {
    n = building(x, y, 15);
  }
}
//}    

void sky() {
  float r= 50;
  float g= 0;
  float b=200;
    background(random(r), random(g), random(b));
    r=constrain(r, 0, 140);
    g=constrain(g, 0, 65);
    b=constrain(b, 0, 255);
  }    

float building(float x, int y, float floorNum) {
  for (int i=0; i<floorNum; i++, y=y-aptSize) {
    a = random(3, 12);
    int b = 7;
    currentFloor= y*aptSize;
    aptRow(x, y, b);
    if (currentFloor<floorNum/3) {
      b=b-1;
    }
  }

  return a;
}    

void aptRow(float x, int y, float aptNum) { 
  for (int j=0; j<aptNum; j++, x=x+aptSize) {
    if (x<width)
      aptUnitA(x, y, aptSize);
  }
}

void aptUnitA(float x, int y, int aptSize) {
  fill(155);
  stroke(0);
  rect(x, y, aptSize, aptSize);
  noStroke();
  fill(242, 235, 53);
  ellipse(x+5, y+5, aptSize/5, aptSize/5);
  ellipse(x+15, y+5, aptSize/5, aptSize/5);
  ellipse(x+10, y+15, aptSize/5, aptSize/2);
}
```

This code is a few buildings. I'm just trying to figure out how to draw a random new set of buildings every time a key is pressed and have some apartment rows that are different sized at the tops of the buildings?

Comment: What are the results when you run this code?  Do you get an error?  What happens?  You can edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

To get keyboard input, you can use the `keyPressed()` function or the `keyPressed` variable. More info is available in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) or in [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) (disclaimer: I wrote that tutorial).

To make the buildings different sizes, you could use the `random()` function to get a random number, then pass that in as the `aptNum` parameter of your `aptRow()` function.

I'd recommend taking a step back and getting something simpler working first. Can you show a single randomly sized rectangle every time the user presses a key? Work your way up from there towards your actual goal.